# Microsoft Access 2003 Will only display views converted to tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I'm running reports in MS Access 2003 which query against our SQL Server 2008 database. Unfortunately when adding new vies to the report form MS Access has begun crashing as soon as I try to view them in anything other than design view.

The program is not throwing out any error messages and the individual views cannot be displayed outside of the report form.

I have converted all of the views to tables as a rather sloppy hack to get these reports up and running. Although this works I'd really like to try and gain a bit more insight into why Access is willing to display some SQL Server views and not others. Note this is not an issue with 2003 I believe because the same behavior is observed in MS Access 2010.

Has anyone run into anything similar? 
Any Ideas what may be causing this?
I'd like to avoid having to use my convoluted table conversion method in the future.